# How to make x*y with simple deep learning(linear regression)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0

For my future use,I wanted to test multivariate multilayer perceptron.

In order to test it, I made a simple python program.

Here's the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

input = []
result = []

for i in range(0,10000):
    x = random.random()*100
    y = random.random()*100
    input.append([x,y])
    result.append(x*y)


input = np.array(input,dtype=float)
result = np.array(result,dtype = float)

activation_func = "relu"
unit_count = 256

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,input_dim=2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count,activation=activation_func),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count,activation=activation_func),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count,activation=activation_func),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count,activation=activation_func),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])

model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse")


model.fit(input,result,epochs=10)

predict_input = np.array([[7,3],[5,4],[8,8]]);

print(model.predict(predict_input))
```

I tried with this code, and the result was not good. The loss value seem not to get lower at some point.

I also tried with smaller x and y. It made model inaccurate with bigger numbers.

I've changed activation function, made more dense layers and increased the number of units but it didnt get better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural networks are not able to adapt themself (without additional training) to a different domain, this means that you should train on a domain and run the inference on the same domain.

In images, we often just scale the input images from [0,255] to the [-1,1] and let the network learn from values in this range (and during inference we rescale always the input values to be in the [-1,1] range).

For solving your tasks you should bring the problem to a restricted domain.

In practice, if you're interested in training a model only for multiplying positive number you can squash them in the [0,1] range, and since the multiplication of values in this range always gives an output value in the same range.

I slightly modified your code and added some comments in the source code.

```py
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

input = []
result = []

# We want to train our network to work in a fixed domain
# the [0,1] range.

# Let's also increase the training set -> more data is always better
for i in range(0, 100000):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    input.append([x, y])
    result.append(x * y)
    print(input, result)
    sys.exit()


input = np.array(input, dtype=float)
result = np.array(result, dtype=float)

activation_func = "relu"
unit_count = 256

# no need for a tons of layers
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count, input_dim=2, activation=activation_func),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(unit_count, activation=activation_func),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
model.fit(input, result, epochs=10)

# Bring our input values in the [0,1] range
max_value = 10
predict_input = np.array([[7, 3], [5, 4], [8, 8]]) / max_value
print(predict_input)

# Back to the original domain
# Multiply by max_value**2 is required since the multiplication
# for a number in [0,1] it's the same of a division
print(model.predict(predict_input) * max_value ** 2)
```

Example output:

```
[[0.7 0.3]
 [0.5 0.4]
 [0.8 0.8]]
[[21.04468 ]
 [20.028284]
 [64.05521 ]]
```

Comment: Is use_bias=False in last Dense layer essential?

Comment: No, it's not, you can have the bias in the last layer although it won't change that much. My intubation suggest that the additive term when performing a multiplication should go to zero (that's why I removed the bias)

Comment: what does the number of layers do? what does it differ from having plenty of unit count?